# Issues in running ipa built with iOS 7 SDK -Xcode 5.0.2- in iOS 8 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have encountered a strange problem and would appreciate help and  suggestions. I have a code base that I can compile and run successfully from Xcode 5.0.2 . Base sdk is iOS 7.0 . I can deploy the ipa created out of this code base from Xcode 5.0.2 in an iOS 8.0 device without an issue.However while fixing a issue I have written the following code :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
        CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform =        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
        self.view.transform = landscapeTransform;
        }
```

This code runs as expected in iOS 8.3 but breaks in iOS 8.0.2 is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: May I know what is reason for Transformation in iOS 8 only

Comment: I have a popover view on the main viewcontroller which when I view in a landscape orientation in iOS 8 comes oriented as landscape- horizontal by default . I want it to be vertically oriented.The popover comes as expected in iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

I have also done the rotation in one of the app. I have used below code.

```
 __block UIImage *newImage = nil;
    void (^rotateImage)(void) = ^{
 UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
        CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
};
```

I have used Block statement. You can add your code there and try once. See if its crashing or not?